# Error while building window application IONIC 3

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

Used 2017 Visual Studio in my Windows-PC and it perfectly add the windows platform to ionic project but it give following error while building. I have install visual studio all plugins as well.

```
$ ionic cordova build windows
Running app-scripts build: --build --iscordovaserve --nobrowser

[19:04:53]  build dev started ...
[19:04:53]  clean started ...
[19:04:53]  clean finished in 8 ms
[19:04:53]  copy started ...
[19:04:53]  transpile started ...
[19:04:57]  transpile finished in 3.58 s
[19:04:57]  preprocess started ...
[19:04:57]  deeplinks started ...
[19:04:57]  deeplinks finished in less than 1 ms
[19:04:57]  preprocess finished in 16 ms
[19:04:57]  webpack started ...
[19:04:57]  copy finished in 3.97 s
[19:05:07]  webpack finished in 10.45 s
[19:05:07]  sass started ...
[19:05:09]  sass finished in 1.76 s
[19:05:09]  postprocess started ...
[19:05:09]  postprocess finished in 8 ms
[19:05:09]  lint started ...
[19:05:09]  build dev finished in 15.87 s
> ionic cordova prepare
> cordova prepare
√ Running command - done!

> cordova build windows
/ Running command [19:05:14]  lint finished in 4.55 s
× Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build windows (exit code 1):

Building project: D:\Mobile\Backup\Fiverr\Godorigins\godorigins\platform       
s\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
Configuration : debug
Platform : anycpu
D:\Mobile\Backup\Fiverr\Godorigins\godorigins\platforms\windows\CordovaA       
pp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program 
Files        

(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.. 
Default.props" was not found.
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct,and that 
the file exists on disk.
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command fail       
ed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you added the windows 10 version in the confg.xml?

Comment: @mcabe yes I have added that.

Comment: try specifying the architecture for your build e.g. ionic cordova build windows -- --archs=ARM